# Protecting a low voltage (RS485) bidirectional bus from direct mains connection

Tags: mains, protection, rs485

I have a bunch of devices that will sit on a two-wire bidirectional RS485 bus (DMX-like, but not quite DMX).

I'm trying to protect against an edge case, where a user mis-wires a ballast, and inadvertently connects mains voltage to the bus, causing the it to become live and potentially injuring anyone else working on it.

I will be installing an 'isolating box' between the bus and the user, essentially behind a wallplate, such that the bus itself can never be directly accessed. The connection to the bus itself would be through opto-isolators and associated circuitry (with a separate isolated supply), however I'd like to 'protect the protection circuitry' if possible, such that it won't catch fire and can gracefully recover.

Would a couple of PTCs, and a couple of TVSs (for redundancy) as below, be enough to reliably save any low voltage circuitry to the left of the circuit, when IO1 and IO2 are connected directly to 240V mains?

[image: rough sketch]

Normally, IO1 and IO2 would see ~22v at roughly 2mA.

Thank you kindly

Comment: You might want to start a step earlier and prevent miswiring on a physical level e.g. by using properly keyed connectors.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in control of this, as this is a manufacturing situation with bare wires and screw terminals (essentially a test bench) - And electricians.

Comment: can you redesign the test bench so that the wrong wires won't reach the wrong terminals?

Comment: Sure, but there are only two terminals on the bench. The device under test has four screw terminals in close proximity and is attached to mains by a cord, which is where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the real world you can never make things totally idiot proof.

If these things are designed to be installed and then left alone, it is foolhardy to add more components than are necessary to protect it from normal operational faults.

If it is meant to be routinely moved around, and or reconnected, then I'd say it maybe more prudent to invest in more protection. Use of TVS though is intended for transients. They will not protect your circuit from being connected to a multi-megawatt power supply. If I really had to do this I would be looking at some form of crow-bar circuit, perhaps using a triac, to detect over voltage, short the line to mains ground, and blow a fuse, possibly a resettable one.

Instead of spending development money on making it bullet-proof and reducing the reliability of the unit as a whole, invest time in preparing clear and concise installation manuals and trust that the electrician can read / do his job properly. If you are really paranoid, add paper tags to the low voltage connections indicating "NO MAINS HERE" or "LOW VOLTAGE CIRCUIT".

If you are getting lots of field returns then analysing what can be done to prevent that is prudent. However, fixing the connectors and improving the documentation is the better approach. Preventing the problem ALWAYS trumps protecting from it.

Comment: I was asked to look into the feasibility of this by a client. Essentially they're testing lighting ballasts prior to shipment, and there's a chance the testers will mis-wire them during tests on the bench. Accidents happen, even out in the field by qualified installers (lots of blown up ballasts due to mis-wiring), I'm just looking for a way to minimise damage/exposure to faults in the lab. Given the feedback that you and others have provided (which I honestly really appreciate), I don't think this is something I'd want to pursue. Thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: @BaudThief if you are getting lots of field returns then analysing what can be done to prevent that is prudent. However, fixing the connectors and improving the documentation is the better approach. Preventing the problem trumps protecting from it.

Comment: @BaudThief BTW: if I really had to do this I would be looking at some form of crow-bar circuit, perhaps using a triac, to detect over voltage, short the line, and blow a fuse, possibly a resettable one.

Comment: Cheers for that. I looked into what you have suggested, and found SIDAC Thyristors (Diodes Inc) are pretty much purpose-built for this kind of situation, when used with a fuse.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to protect against an edge case, where a user mis-wires a
>   ballast, and inadvertently connects mains voltage to the bus, causing
>   the it to become live and potentially injuring anyone else working on
>   it

Use a [GCFI or residual current device](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFCI) so that the AC becomes disconnected within a few milliseconds of an inappropriate connection. This will save lives but won't necessarily save components on the bus.

To save bus components the GFCI will need supplementing with some circuit that can handle "the overload" for up to 30 milli seconds before the GFCI kicks in.

You may get away with PTCs but without knowing which one you intend to use I cannot be sure and I'm not going searching for one that will.

Comment: GFCI is a good idea I think under the circumstances you probably need to sacrifice the bus components to the great god of the magic smoke.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but each bench is already equipped with an RCD - Perhaps I should have left out the human safety aspect, and asked how I would go about protecting only the attached circuitry. This is more of a secondary measure in case existing measures fail

Comment: You should always consider questions thoughtfully. I can only read what you write and because safety trumps reliability this was what I concentrated on. Apart from anything else, you have given no detail of the protection device so how can anyone really help you?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, unfortunately communication doesn't appear to be my strong point. I didn't want to overload the question with detail that wouldn't add any value and cause confusion. I was hoping for some general direction as to whether the TVS's and PTCs themselves would be sufficient protection /in general/ for low voltage circuitry on the left, or if there are alternatives/additions that I should consider (ie: crowbar and a fuse). In any case, thank you.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You ask the question and the best questions are specific and link to data sheets etc. and have diagrams. If the detail in the diagrams looks wrong you will get help and alternative ideas but without the detail nobody can answer specifically on the parts you have drawn.

Comment: +1 Good advice here for sure, though a CGI likely will not do much if the AC is hooked across the RS485 connections.

Comment: @Trevor_G I guess the chances of both wires being hooked simultaneously within a few mili seconds of each other is unlikely LOL.

Comment: Ya that too, but I meant if you hook up the main to the optically isolated bus you will blow the couplers but there may be no ground current. Current likely wont be high enough to pop the breaker either.

Comment: a GFCI won't protect isolated RS485 circuitry. and probably won't be fast enough to protect a grounded one.

Comment: @Jasen correct I did say it offers protection after about 30 ms hence the job of the electronic protection is made simpler because it only has to deal with the first 30 ms overload. If you read the question it talks about safety and damage.